# Is a question about a Windows iPhone image type that turns out to be just about settings on the iPhone a better fit for Ask Different SE?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked [How to browse the iPhone HEIC images on Windows without the automatic conversion to JPG?](https://superuser.com/questions/1805536/how-to-browse-the-iphone-heic-images-on-windows-without-the-automatic-conversion)

and found out that the fix is on the side of the iPhone settings. Windows does not play a role for the problem, though I thought when I asked. If this is now clearly an "Apple question", should it be moved there? Or is it still a good fit on Super User?

With this question, I want to find out whether I should flag it for a moderator to move it to Ask Different Stack Exchange.

Comment: If the problem is absolutely isolated to the iPhone then I would say it is a question that belongs on Ask Different. Your problem is slightly on the cusp though. Something about your computer triggers iOS to do something, but the problem is entirely an iOS one. I'm torn because this is something that affects how your computer sees it, but the problem is your phone.

Comment: @Mokubai OK, I will ask to move it then.